# Send template as a mail

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I am quite struggling regarding this issue. I want to send the mail to the user with html as a template.But the code is not at all working, I am storing the htmlpage url in one variable and appending to the mail but it is not displaying the content of the html .Can any one help me?`

```
                        var html = '/index1.html';
                            transporter.sendMail({
                            from : xxxx@gmail.com,
                            to : xxxx@gmail.com,
                            subject : 'Invitation',
                            html : html
                        });
                    `
```

Comment: Your `html` variable is just a string with the value `/index1.html` not an actual page. :)

Comment: Means you are saying complete path to mention?

Comment: No. Even if you mention complete path, it will still be a `string` not the actual file. Please check the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `html` variable is just a string with the value `/index1.html` not an actual page. :)

If you're using jQuery, you can do it by fetching the contents of `index1.html` like

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/index1.html',
    success: function (htmlContent) { // htmlContent will have your html markup
        transporter.sendMail({
            from : xxxx@gmail.com,
            to : xxxx@gmail.com,
            subject : 'Invitation',
            html : htmlContent // set your html to the markup read from ./index1.html
        });
    }
});
```

EDIT:

Updating after OP's latest comment

If you're doing this on the backend, you can use `fs` module of node to read the file

```
var fs = require("fs");
var filename = "./index1.html";

var data = fs.readFileSync(filename); //data will have contents of your index1.html

transporter.sendMail({
    from : xxxx@gmail.com,
    to : xxxx@gmail.com,
    subject : 'Invitation',
    html : data
});
```

Comment: How can we handle the transporter.sendmail in the ajax call, it is related to backend can u explain how can we do?

Comment: I am getting an error although the path is correct ENOENT, no such file or directory '../home/index1.html'

Comment: try giving absoluiite path to your index1.html

Comment: Thanks it is working, one small doubt , I am getting the data from backend want to append in the html. How can I perform